# SQL Server CE private deployment for C# class library used in multiple apps

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

I'm using SQL Server CE and the Entity Framework in a C# class library. This library is used in at least three applications, i.e. the "main" program,  the unit tests and the integration tests.

We decided to use SQL Server CE in prvate deployment mode (copying all needed files to the executables folder), and this works fine for the main program. When using the class library in the test, which run in other directories, we need to copy the SQL Server CE DLLs to each of these folder, which produces redundancy with all its problems.

What would be the recommended way to solve this? GAC? Set codebase in configuration?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, we found our way to deploy the DLLs with our tests. It's not worth mentioning here how, as it is not applicable to this problem in general but rather a custom solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use DeploymentItem atttribute in your test classes (can copy entire folders)